# Insert data into a column based on a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This may sound a little tricky.  I have a table that has columns from Jan2012 - March2015.  Each month has it's own column.

I am creating a query that is a loop where it calculates the total number of visits from the trailing 12 months per doctor.  So basically it does something similar to this but much more involved.

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = '20110101'
Declare @EndDate  as Date = Dateadd(mm, 12, @Startdate)
Declare @Column as VarChar(15) = DateName(MM, @EndDate) + DateName(YY, @EndDate)

Create Table #Final
(
     DoctorID      Int
     January2012   Int
     February2012  Int
     March2012     Int
     ....
)

Select
DoctorID
Count(InvoiceID) Over (Partition By HospitalID, DoctorID) as CountofVisits
From
Invoice
```

Now what I want to do is insert the Count of visits into the proper column based on the End Date.  This query will loop through each month for the time period.

Thanks,

Comment: If you have the ability to modify your schema, I would recommend normalizing this table.  Rather than having a column for every month, create a linked table for visits that has three columns to handle that job: DoctorID, VisitDate and InvoiceID.  This means that you don't have to add a new clumn to your table every month.  And it allows you to aggregate data (like count of visits) without jumping through hoops like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many other things that need to be done in order for this to happen.  I just showed a simplified version- it is actually much longer where I Have to limit it to one doctor per patient based on the revenue spent over the period.  along with other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the column you are inserting into prior to executing the query, which means you have sadly entered into the land of dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL works by setting a variable equal to a text string, and then using the exec command on the variable. It's not rocket science, but it might be a bit more of an explanation that comfortably fits in a stack overflow answer. Fortunately Pinal Dave explained it already, and probably much better than I can:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/28/sql-server-executing-dynamic-sql-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-4-query-programming-objects-for-sql-server-2012/

The answer you are looking for is about half way down the page, but I'd suggest reading the whole thing as it's very informative.

As fair warning, dynamic sql generally sucks on performance, when combined with a loop, you are probably looking at something that will get DBAs concerned.